# update netsuite parent field via suitescript in view mode

Tags: netsuite

I have scripts that react off of, for example, a client Recalc client event. For example, on my form I have a subtab that users may add or remove items from. Based on actions on this subtab (housing a child record of the parent) I would like a field on the parent to update (say to show a total from the children records).

As I was saying, these events seem to work fine if in edit mode but they do not work correctly in view mode. (even in view mode these child records have a "Delete" option at the end of each row in the subtab. This was provided by netsuite by default.

I wondered if anyone had any tips to best allow this parent field to update real time while in updating the subtab rows with the form in view mode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom field on the parent (header) whose value is determined by saved search. For instance, make a saved search that totals the line values by transaction. Be sure to make it filter by transaction in the Available Filters tab. Make the search public so everyone can use it.

Create the custom field that sources the total from the saved search. Make sure to uncheck the "Store Value" checkbox, as you don't want to store the data, you want to reference the search results. You do this on the Validation and Defaulting tab. You'll see a field for Saved Search there. Choose the search you created above.

As you remove/add/change lines on the transaction, the field updates accordingly. In essence, you don't need a single line of code to make this work - it's all in how you create the search and the custom field that references it.

Comment: This is a good idea but even if that does work, the issue I would have with it is I read that calculated fields only update on the page load.

Comment: I tried to put code in to count the child messages on the recal event and that works fine in Edit mode but i cant get it to fire in view mode (such as when you press "remove" by an item in a sublist).  Events dont seem to fire in view mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442386/how-to-set-a-fields-value-on-the-view-mode-of-a-netsuite-custom-record-using-c).

The NetSuite team answered me by email, and it happens you can't really achieve this on the view mode: some API methods are not available. Their suggestion to my case (and I think it applies to yours too) was really to force a refresh on the whole page.

Of course, you can always achieve this accessing the DOM elements directly, but this isn't a best practice, as your code can stop working if these elements change on a version update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I'm not able to restrict on view or remove edit button. But, there was one alternative solution with workflows, you can deploy workflow on child record edit mode restrictions, then if the user clicks edit on view then the record will not be available to edit. This concern will apply to custom record as well.